Drawing up to 12kW through a NEMA 14-50R at 120V
The 14-50R has L1, L2, Neutral and GND connections. Of course, you can draw 12kW across L1 and L2 by pulling 50A from the circuit. In this case, there is 50A flowing in each of the L1 and L2 wires with none on the Neutral. In the situation where L1 and L2 are used as a 2x120 connection (appliances needing 120V using L1-N and L2-N for their circuits), it seems that you could draw the same 12kW by drawing 50A from L1-N and 50A from L2-N.
My first reaction to this was to say it shouldn't be allowed because this would mean we were drawing 100A from the neutral. But I pulled out Excel and rotated through an entire cycle (360-degrees) and calculated the current draw on each circuit assuming that L1 and L2 are 120-degrees apart. Sure enough, the current on the Neutral never gets above 50A.
So I assume this means that I can put a 50A breaker on L1 and L2 and no breaker on the Neutral and be fine. Then when I'm drawing 12kW from 120V appliances, both phases and the neutral would have 50A on them. Correct?

Did you really mean to assume that "L1 and L2 are 120-degrees apart" rather than 180 degrees? You mention 12 kW and 50 A which would imply 240 V between L1 and L2. But 3-phase usually has 208 V between any two phases.

This is theoretically correct but it seems contrived to have a setting you could feed through a single plug like this (residential single unit, and???) and also have so much power used strictly at 120V and perfectly balanced.  Where do you find this in nature?

In response to @JimStewart, my understanding is that in a residential or commercial setting that the phases are always 120-degrees apart. Is there some situation where phases are delivered 180-degrees apart?

In response to @jay613, this is found in most every RV that uses a 50A plug like the NEMA 14-50P on the unit. There are (almost) never appliances in an RV that use 240V directly -- everything is run like two 120V circuits.

Fair enough, I don't know about RVs but if that is exactly how they all are configured, what's the question?  Also how would you put a breaker on the neutral even if you wanted to?  I think the question is more about the math of split phase power delivery?  That is a good question but doesn't belong in this forum.

OP, do you have 3-phase service or 120 / 240 V split phase? With the latter the phases  are 180 deg apart

Congrats, you just invented the multi-wire branch circuit.
Yes, in a 120/240V split-phase situation, the neutral will carry only the differential current.   In fact, for wire thermal rise calculations, it's rather neat: thermal rise is proportional to current squared, and at any ampacity on either hot, L12 + L22 + N2 is <= 2 x rating2.  Therefore, 120/240V MWBCs count only as 2 wires for thermal adjustment/derate.
In a 120/208V 3-phase situation, neutral will not exceed phase current.  This allows MWBCs of both proper 3-phase (H-H-H-N) and "3-phase but only 2 phases delivered" (H-H-N).  With full 3-phase, again, maxing out all the hots results in zero neutral current.
And the same trick still works: at any current on any of the three hots, the thermal impact is still <= that of only 3 wires. L12 + L22 + L32 + N2 is <= 3 x rating2. So again neutral does not count, and full 3-phase H-H-H-N MWBC counts only as 3 wires.
However, as you analyzed, the "2 of 3 phases" H-H-N circuit does not work like a 120/240V MWBC. With both hot wires at max, neutral current is also high.  That means it still counts as 3 wires even though it an MWBC, because of the 3-phase source.  Think of it as a full 3-phase MWBC with permanently 0 amps on L3.
Oh. One other thing. Regarding pulling 50A through a NEMA 14-50 style socket, be aware of the experience of EVers - they frequently see the cheapie under-$30 "range-grade outlets" melt under EV service, which mind you is only 32A (on the assumption that a 14-50 receptacle may have a 40A breaker per NEC 210.21).  They recommend the Hubbell/Bryant, which are "RV park grade" (RVs unlike ranges are plug/unplugged practically every day), and seem to perform well under EV loads.

Personally I’m a fan of Meltric connectors since they are rated to contain any arcing in the plug (a barrier engages before the plug comes apart).

Thanks for the great info. Of course I didn't actually create this idea -- I'm doing some wiring in a 5th wheel and this is the way it's wired. I installed a Victron Multi Plus II in my 5th wheel which necessitated that I break the connection from the external NEMA 14-50P and the breaker panel and insert the Multi Plus in the middle. I needed to add a breaker between the new Multi Plus and the 14-50P. Before I thought to ask the question, I put a breaker on all three wires (HHN) out of caution, but it seems that the correct thing to have done would have been a 2-pole handle-tied breaker.

@Stephen Hicks either way as long as you're not creating redundant neutral paths.  However if you breaker the neutral, a neutral trip must "common trip" both hots.  That's code but ask any RVer about lost neutrals.   The two hots don't need common trip to each other if all loads are 120V hot to ground, but they do need a handle tie so a maintinainers cut off the whole thing.

@Jon that only solves series arcing during insert/remove.  The sockets we're seeing melt are underway.

Harper's covers how/why this works.
But the related question is why do this?
There are very few single breakers (i.e., 120V) larger than 30A. Why? Because there are very few 120V loads that require that much power. Whether a load is a large heating or motor or EV charging load, bumping up to 240V is the normal thing to do if you need more than around 3,000 Watts for an appliance. Yes, it adds another breaker. But 3,000 W at 120V requires 10 AWG wire. At 240V it only requires 14 AWG wire. A 4,500 W to 5,500 W continuous (a.k.a, a typical tank water heater) requires 10 AWG wire at 240V. If you tried to run the same device but redesigned to output 4,500 W of power at 120V (because you need power to generate resistance heat) it would require 8 AWG or 6 AWG wire (depending on wire and cable type). That heavier wire costs a lot more than thinner wire.
On the other hand, a 50A circuit with neutral can be converted into a subpanel feed, and that subpanel could power any appropriate mix of 120V and/or 240V loads.

This wasn't really my decision. I'm doing some wiring in a 5th wheel and this is the way it's wired. I installed a Victron Multi Plus II in my 5th wheel which necessitated that I break the connection from the external NEMA 14-50P and the breaker panel and insert the Multi Plus in the middle. I needed to add a breaker between the new Multi Plus and the 14-50P. In a unit like this, multiple loads such as a refrigerator, A/C unit, microwave, etc. are all placed on the same hot circuit. This wouldn't be done in a residential setting, of course, but in a trailer it's common practice.
